# Android: Get Spinner Data from a Recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I creating a feedback screen in an application in which user will have to  select their opinion(displayed as `Spinner`) for each question(`TextView`).
Multiple questions & options will be  displayed in a `RecylcerView`. On clicking submit button, I need to get all the data(Both Question and Selected spinner value) from recycler view and send to the server.

I saw the many suggesting to **implement `onItemSelectedListener`** on the `Spinner`. It **will not suitable for me because Each spinner will have default value**. Also user may not select each and every spinner.

How to get the value of each spinner(Opinion) & Textview(Question) inside `ViewHolder` of a `RecyclerView`

Comment: what have you implemented so far?

Comment: you can add listener or create public method in you main activity when the spinner item selected change , you can send your data to this method

Comment: @Ali Rahman The problem is user may not select any spinner . They may simply click `Submit` because the spinner will have default value. In that case,  data will be empty

Comment: @kampangala what we have implemented is onclick listener on the spinner

Comment: What I meant @Avinash is show us your implementation so we know what you actually get and what you expect to get

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** You must have Model class say `Question` like below

```
public class Question {
   String questionTitle;
   List<Answer> answerList;
   // getter/setter
}

public class Answer {
   boolean isSelected;
   boolean isDefault;
   // getter/setter
}
```

**Step 2:** You must be passing list of Question to your adapter. And on item click simply set the answer as selected using `answer.setSelected(true)` for the particular question.

**Step 3:** Create a method in adapter class like below which will give you the selected answers for all the question.

```
public Map<String,Answer> getSelectedAnswers() {
    Map<String,Answer> map = new HashMap();
    for(Question question : questionList){
         List<Answer> answers = question.getAnswerList();
         Answer defaultAnswer;
         for (Answer answer: answers){
           if(answer.isSelected()){
             map.put(question.questionTitle(),answer);
             defaultAnswer = null;
             break;
           } 
           if(answer.isDefault()) {
              defaultAnswer = answer;
           }
         }
         if(defaultAnswer != null) {
            map.put(question.questionTitle(),defaultAnswer);
         }
    }
    return map;
}
```

**Note :** If step 3 want to avoid then keep a `Map<String, Answer> selectionMap` in the adapter itself where is **key** would be question and **value** would be a selected answer for that question, and keep updating on spinner item selection.

**Step 4:** At the time of calling API on submit button you need to traverse Map and then wrap into required fields what API expects.

Comment: What if a user not selected any answer for a question?

Comment: Then you will get empty Map. which make sense

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and response. I am looking for other ways to get data from spinner(or any other input widgets) inside recyclerview apart from setting onclick listener.  When the user clicks the submit button, I need to get data of all 
 input widget(in this case spinner) inside a recyclerview  and send it to server. In your answer, Again onItemClickListener is used.

Comment: Yeah it's upto you ! I don't see any issue adding click listener. If you want to avoid click listener then definitely you have to hold list of spinner and need to iterate each of them . Which is not a preferable way to do that holding list of views inside adapter class.

Comment: @Avinash now have updated approach in answer to get the default answers if you has not selected any answer and pressed Submit button.